# How to code for API 16 in Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem with Apache Cordova.
My mobile phone is running Android 4.1.1.
And I wanted to test my future apps directly on my phone (not with the emulator).
But, Cordova always want the latest version (API 19) but I want API 16.
So, if you have any solutions, please tell it.
Best Reguards,
DJPOC

Comment: Check [android:minSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a file named AndroidManifest.xml in the platforms/android directory.

In that file is markup similar to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

You can change these SDK versions to suit your needs.